# iOS App Search - how to search on different words to return same app, regardless app (display) name

Tags: ios, xcode

Basically - the display name of the Xbox SmartGlass application is a good example, so, the text below the app is "SmartGlass", but, I can do a search on the iPhone for "Xbox" and the app will be returned in the results. I was wondering where in Xcode do I need to set the proper values to do the same thing.

Comment: rmaddy i'm not referring to the app store searching, i'm talking about on device searching - swipe to the left searching. is this what you're referring to as well? if so, how would anyone be able to test...

Comment: Did you ever find the answer, @crizzwald?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the reason for this is because the full name of the app (as it appears in the App Store) is  "Xbox SmartGlass".  While the display name is "SmartGlass" the full name contains Xbox.  Another example is the app "Robot Unicorn Attack 2" The display name on the device is just "RUA2" but searching for "robot", "unicorn" or "attack" all show that app in the results.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is on the App Store you can make search words in your meta data.  You can place any word you want there. You can do this when you submit as well. But if you didn't, you can log into itc, click on manage apps, click on the app and then edit the meta data. This is where you can have screen shots and such. There is a section to place search terms. I submitted an app that solves the quadratic equation, my search terms are quadratic, equation, solver, and formula.  Good luck.

Comment: The metadata you specify in iTunes Connect is only for App Store searches, not on-device searching.

Comment: thanks Douglas for the useful info, however, i'm speaking in terms of the on-device search as Simeon Goldeen stated.

Comment: Got it, thought you were searching the App Store not on the device!